# Remove class during orientation change in sencha touch 2

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to remove class during orientation change

**View.js**

```
  itemCls: 'dataview-item',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div class="arHeadline">',
                '    {Headline}',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="arbyline">',
                '    {Author}',
                '</div>',
                '<div class="arcontent">',
                '    {Content}',
                '</div>',
                '<div id="myline"class="ardrawline">',
                '</div>'

            ],
```

**Controller.js**

```
orientationChangeHandler : function(viewport,orientation,width,height){
    var domEl1 = Ext.get('myline');
    console.log("els "+domEl1);

    if (orientation === "landscape") {
        domEl1.addCls('ardrawline');
    } else {
        domEl1.removeCls('ardrawline');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the same IDs for each item -> id="myline"

For example you can define your template:

```
<div data-type="myline" class="ardrawline">
```

and then you can select your elements as follow:

```
Ext.DomQuery.select("div[@data-type='myline']");
```